# Get date elements as strings

Tags: date

I want to know if there is a way to get the *date elements* (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) in order to create a lucky of version number that automatically increments. For example if now it is 15:30 hs of March 19 of the year 2018, I would like to generate a number like: 201803191530 where the format is YYYYMMDDHHmm. I would like to have the possibility to arrange the elements in any way. It would be ideal some sort of comands like `\year \month \day \hour \minute \second`, for example, so then I can use them as I wish.

Comment: Have you seen the `datetime2` package? It allows you to access the date and time with customized formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An expandable time stamp definition without any package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\timestamp{%
  \the\year
  \two@digits\month
  \two@digits\day
  \two@digits{\numexpr(\time*2 - 59)/120\relax}%
  \two@digits{\numexpr\time - 60*\numexpr(\time*2 - 59)/120\relax\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\typeout{Time stamp: \timestamp}

\begin{document}
  Time stamp: \timestamp
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\time` gets the minutes of the day.
- e-TeX's `\numexpr` allows expandable calculations. However, it rounds. The complicate formulas work around it.
- `\two@digits` comes from the LaTeX kernel and is intended for positive integers. If the number is less than 10, it adds a preceding zero.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pdflatex`, you can use `\pdfcreationdate` that records the time stamp when the PDF file is opened for output, which is a string of the form

```
D:20170421011556+02’00’
```

The last seven characters represent the difference with UTC. So it's just a matter of parsing the string. I added a possible definition for your time stamp, reorder the items at will.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\set@time@data#1:#2\@nil{\set@time@data@a#2}
\def\set@time@data@a#1#2#3#4{%
  \gdef\Year{#1#2#3#4}%
  \set@time@data@b
}
\def\set@time@data@b#1#2#3#4{%
  \gdef\Month{#1#2}%
  \gdef\Day{#3#4}%
  \set@time@data@c
}
\def\set@time@data@c#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \gdef\Hour{#1#2}%
  \gdef\Min{#3#4}%
  \gdef\Sec{#5#6}%
  \set@time@data@d
}
\def\set@time@data@d#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{}
% start up the business
\expandafter\set@time@data\pdfcreationdate\@nil
\endgroup
\edef\TimeStamp{\Year-\Month-\Day\space\Hour:\Min:\Sec}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Time stamp: \TimeStamp

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Year & \Year \\
Month & \Month \\
Day & \Day \\
Hour & \Hour \\
Min & \Min \\
Sec & \Sec \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar, but with clearer syntax (here I just define the `\TimeStamp` macro); just move around the various ranges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npx \TimeStamp
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 3 } { 6 } % year
  -
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 7 } { 8 } % month
  -
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 9 } { 10 } % day
  \space
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 11 } { 12 } % hour
  :
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 13 } { 14 } % minutes
  :
  \str_range:Nnn \pdfcreationdate { 15 } { 16 } % seconds
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Time stamp: \TimeStamp

\end{document}
```

[image]