# Happy Pi day to applied scientists!

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, date

Happy Pi day to all non-American applied mathematicians and scientists (like me) who make approximations!

This is in fact TeX related as I have a question, or perhaps a puzzle. How would I make the equation

`$\pi \approx \today$`

give the output that makes sense, given the appropriate formatting of today's date. Furthermore, suppose the equation were typeset tomorrow, one might like it to output `\pi \neq \today', if you see what I mean. And if it were typeset on March 14, it might give yet a different answer. I'm afraid I don't have any MWEs for these.

Answer (score 2):

You are a bit late, aren't you? ;-) See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420083/pi-day-riddles-for-latex-users) for funny posts along these lines. Just kidding. ;-)

Here is something like a more serious answer, based on [Heiko's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422050/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\edef\mydate{% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422050/121799
  \two@digits\month
  \two@digits\day
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\piday{0314}
\ifx\mydate\piday%
happy $\pi$ day
\else
sorry, not a $\pi$ day
\fi
\end{document}
```

OK, here for Europeans. (Sorry for loading Ti*k*Z, which is not at all necessary here but I happen to love it. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\edef\myday{% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422050/121799
  \two@digits\day
}
\edef\mymonth{
  \two@digits\month
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\test}{100*\myday/\mymonth}
\def\mypi{314}
\ifx\test\mypi%
happy European $\pi$ day
\else
sorry, not a European $\pi$ day
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for the Pi day celebrated in America by mathematicians, but not for today's Pi day for European scientists  :)

Comment: @GeoffV **NOW** I got the point (even though I am a European marmot;-)

Comment: @marmot +1 I'll have to include this date formatting  in my beamer theme: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132370/how-to-number-slides-with-an-increasing-number-of-digits-of-pi :)

Comment: @samcarter I should have known because I had upvoted that before... thanks for the +1 ... I'll be happy to remove this if you think the question is a duplicate or so....

Comment: @marmot Not at all a duplicate, please do not remove. I just wanted to mention, that your code is a nice addition to my theme.